# Instantiate ES6 class from variable

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to instantiate a new object from a class based on a variable in ES6?

This is my scenario:

```
class SomeClass {
    hasMany(what){

        var instance = new window[what]();

        var owned_objects = instance.allOwnedBy(this.constructor.name, self.id);

        return instance;
    }
}
```

However, this returns `Uncaught TypeError: window.Group is not a constructor(…)`

the hasMany is located within a Class. So what I want to achieve is that the function within this class, should instantiate another class based on the name of that class passed as a variable, and then return the instance.

Comment: is hasMany a method of another class?

Comment: I assume the `Group` class is not defined in the global scope?

Comment: Correct @GOTO. the window[what] was a far fetch. I tried with just new what(). I tried: this[what] = what, and new what() etc. the Group class is just defined with: class Group { ...

Comment: @OleHaugset If you don't have any moral concerns using `eval`, you could try `var instance = new (eval(what))();`

Comment: That works @GOTO, but the gut feeling is just that its terribly wrong :P

Answer (score 0):

How are you defining `class Group`?

In my tests, it'd work if you specifically set the class as a property of window. So:

```
window.Group = class {...}
```

Then you can do:

```
var instance = new window['Group']();
```

Comment: It would work, yes, but you still shouldn't do that.

Comment: I'm not really a "don't pollute the window object" activist, but yeah. He could also make a dict with all the references and access that.